# convert array to array of objects using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a help, how to convert an array to array of objects.

Eg: may be this is the array

```
let a = ["abc", "mno"]
```

I want it to be like this:

```
let b = [
  {
    "text": "abc"
  },
  {
    "text": "mno"
  }
]
```

please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const a = [ "abc", "mno" ];
const b = a.map( ( item ) => { return {text:item} } );

console.log('a => ', a)
console.log('b => ', b)
```

explanation :

array.map is looping to every element of the array and if you provide return it will create new array from the return of every element

in this case the return is an object of `{ text:item }` by item being the element of which index on the loop

Answer (score 1):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`arrow notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) should do it:

`.map()` -> loops over an array and returns a transformed array.
With arrow functions you need not right `return` statement if you skip the curly braces along. Enclose them in parentheses (`()`) whenever you want to return an object.

```js
let a = ["abc", "mno"];
let b = a.map(item => ({"text" : item}));
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of *array*.forEach and *array*.push function to do so.